# Proxy class not available for Windows Phone 7 Reference to WCF Service

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I have an existing WCF service that works. I've added a reference in Visual Studio 2010 for my Windows Phone app. The reference shows up and I see the methods when I check out the properties of it. The service is using basicHttpBinding. It seems the proxy class is never generated. I cannot reference it (yes - I'm checking the proper namespace)

I'm aware of the SlSvcUtil.exe utility - but that is supposed to not be necessary anymore. Any thoughts as to why my proxy class isn't being generated but the service reference is there?

Thanks!

EDIT: Wsdl file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ProjectManager" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://somesite/ProjectManager/ProjectManager.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://somesite/ProjectManager/ProjectManager.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://somesite/ProjectManager/ProjectManager.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ProjectManager" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IProjectManagerService_GetProjectList_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProjectList" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IProjectManagerService_GetProjectList_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProjectListResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IProjectManagerService_GetProjectFiles_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProjectFiles" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IProjectManagerService_GetProjectFiles_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetProjectFilesResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IProjectManagerService">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProjectList">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IProjectManagerService/GetProjectList" message="tns:IProjectManagerService_GetProjectList_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IProjectManagerService/GetProjectListResponse" message="tns:IProjectManagerService_GetProjectList_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProjectFiles">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IProjectManagerService/GetProjectFiles" message="tns:IProjectManagerService_GetProjectFiles_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IProjectManagerService/GetProjectFilesResponse" message="tns:IProjectManagerService_GetProjectFiles_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IProjectManagerService" type="tns:IProjectManagerService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProjectList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IProjectManagerService/GetProjectList" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="GetProjectFiles">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IProjectManagerService/GetProjectFiles" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ProjectManager">
    <wsdl:port name="BasicHttpBinding_IProjectManagerService" binding="tns:BasicHttpBinding_IProjectManagerService">
      <soap:address location="http://somesite/ProjectManager/ProjectManager.svc" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: If you select the "Project -> Show all files" option when selecting the WP7 project, and you expand the service reference icon, do you see the reference.cs file?

Comment: no, just the wdsl, disco, svcinfo, svcmap, and xsd files.

Comment: Is there anything under the svcmap file (IIRC the .cs file is listed under that)? If not, is there any warning / error on VS when you add the reference? If not, then it may be worth trying to use slsvcutil to generate a file - even if just to find out if it emits any error / warnings.

Comment: ah ya.. an empty reference.cs under the svcmap file. I had tried the slsvc util previously and it works just fine (no errors and a proper cs file), but the add svc reference is 'supposed' to work just fine now so trying to figure out the cause of that.

Comment: Can you share the wsdl files for your service?

Comment: wsdl file added above. I changed the site name.. and I know.. I still have tempuri.org... still in development : )

Comment: And the .xsd files as well so I can try around here :) The WSDL has three xsd:import elements; if you replace ?wsdl with ?xsd=xsd0/1/2 it will show you the schema files imported by the WSDL.

Comment: Carlos - send me an email I'll send you the url of the service if youd like to try that from your end. im gmail , adam.tuliper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough - a month later it started working with no other installs. Its possible that a recent reboot 'fixed' it but thought I had rebooted prior as well - who knows though. Either way its working.

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me.

Not sure what causes it.

What works for me is to close down Visual Studio, reopen, right click on the service and click Update Service Reference.

Answer (score 2):

I got exactly the same problem. And installing the "Windows Phone Developer Tools Fix" solved the problem.

Here is the link to download the fix: http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/D/6/6D66958D-891B-4C0E-BC32-2DFC41917B11/VS10-KB2486994-x86.exe

Good luck!

Comment: hmm.. I'll try - I thought this was already installed but I'll check. thanks!

Comment: what version of VS are you using? Professional?

Comment: Ultimate - the problem resolved itself interestingly enough. +1 though since this solution worked for you

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem.
Adding the service again with another name solved the problem for me once or twice.
Slsvc works every time and is much nicer to work with when checking into TFS.
Not sure if this is TFS related or not.

Comment: tried that too in the past.. no go. slsvc I wanted to stay away from just purely as in my view the IDE should do this ok except for extreme cases. this case is very basic.